# when does product of maps being zero implies acyclicity

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a polynomial ring and $R^n\xrightarrow{\phi_1}R^m\xrightarrow{\phi_2} R^s$ be such that $\phi_2\circ\phi_1=0$. Let the rank of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be $r_1,r_2$ respectively. Then does $\operatorname{grade} I_{r_1}(\phi_1)\geq 1$ and $\operatorname{grade} I_{r_2}(\phi_2)\geq 2$ imply the above complex is exact?

It has bearing on the theorem of Buchsbaum-Eisenbud. They show that for a complex of free modules $0\rightarrow F_n\xrightarrow{\phi_n} \cdots F_2\rightarrow F_1\xrightarrow{\phi_1} F_0\rightarrow 0$ such that the rank of $\phi_i=r_i$. Then the complex is acyclic if and only if $\operatorname{grade} I_{r_i}(\phi_i)\geq i$ for every $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $R=k[x,y,z]$ with $\phi_1=(y,-x,0), \phi_2=(x,y,z)^T$. Then $r_i=1$, $\phi_2\circ\phi_1=0$, grade conditions are satisfied, but it is not exact. Am I missing something here?